# Firefox 60.6.1esr Ctrl-W sometimes closes multiple tabs

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, tabs

#### Problem

During problem-solving, I often open many new tabs, close some of them one-by-one, and close the remaining ones when I'm done.  I usually (but not always) close my tabs via `Ctrl-W`.

Sometimes (say, about 1 time out of 10) the `Ctrl-W` key combination (but never a click on a tab close button) will not only close the current tab, but also a few more, typically 1 to 5, which is extremely annoying.

#### Context

My browser configuration (I'm on Windows 10) is not overly complex. The most conspicuous specialty being that I use a CSS extension to show multiple rows of tabs.

#### Analysis

I have not yet found any pattern in this behavior (say, regarding the position of the tab, its age, its content, or position/age/content of the additionally closed tabs), except that I *think* it only happens when I have used `Ctrl-W` one or more times "recently" before.

#### Question

A web search did not turn up any hint of this problem for anybody else.
Any advice what I should do?

Comment: Does a regular `W` keypress ever insert multiple letters?

Comment: @grawity No, my keyboard appears to work just like it should.

Comment: When you say it closes 1-5 tabs, is this usually the whole Firefox window? Could it possible be an accidental `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`W`? I've done that before and it's annoying to lose everything open

Comment: @MC10 No, it's not the whole window. Several tabs close, but several others remain open.